# Google Cloud for High Reading Transactions; which product I should choose?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I will be having just single data table with 9 Million rows. My Python application will need to read small chunk of data through 60,000 separate queries which will be run through loop and process data for complex classification. I want to achieve this in as little time as possible.   Can somebody suggest which Google cloud product should I use; Big table, Big Query, Data Store, Cloud SQl, Spanner etc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't forget to visit the site's [tour] and see [what topics can be asked about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Any question asking us to recommend an off-site resource, including cloud services, are off-topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of the products you've listed [BiqQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) is probably the best choice for the problem that you're describing and the types of queries that you're looking at running against it.

Also look at [Introduction to BigQuery ML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigqueryml-intro) as there might be some suitable use cases for your classification problem.

Comment: Thanks Scott! Haven't tried yet but hoping Bigquery to work significantly faster